# Пропажа файлов базы данных в Android

Tags: база-данных, восстановление

Делаем на планшете софт для сбора статистики. Приложение не сложное оболочка для работой с базой SQlite. 
Случился такой случай, пользователь работая с приложением заметил как экран устройства погас(потемнел если дословно), и после этого программа вылетела при этом "пропал" файл базы данных, а приложение без него не запустится.
Я с таким раньше не сталкивался. Восстановить не получилось. Само приложение не имеет функции удаления файлов с базой, видимо файл был удален системно... планшет Lenovo, версия андройда 2.3.3, к интернету подключения нет.

**Что можно  сделать что бы предупредить/исправить подобные события вновь?**

Вот тут подобная проблема: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/KJNdYMcGZlM

Comment: Гадание на кофейной гуще: троян, ошибка в другом софте, аппаратный сбой и т.д.

Comment: а вот интересно, планшет рутованный был?

Comment: @ermakOff    
Да. Рут права есть, скриптами забираю базу с планшета, так же закидываю для тестов